# Odoo export arabic text

Tags: odoo, arabic, odoo-9

I'm working on an Arabic project my problem is there is a lot of string in `xml` are hardcoded on arabic letters, but when I try to export the translation this string doesn't appear on the printout file in `python` when I add:

```
 string=u"som arabic text"
```

The words are exported but how to do this in xml views?

Comment: Are you using odoo 8 or 9?

Comment: i'm using 9  but if there is a solution in 8 i will take it also

Comment: @Charif: If you have hard embedded string  into the view then they can not be translated

Comment: do you have any idea why or how we can make it happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got why the Arabic terms are not exported in the .PO file for translation the problem is in this file :

```
openerp/tools/tranlate.py
```

in the line : `777` or `776` there is an instruction to remove non-alphanumeric chars but this instructions don't take the Arabic terms in consideration to do so in python27 change :

```
sanitized_term = re.sub(r'\W+', '', sanitized_term)
```

to

```
sanitized_term = re.sub(r'\W+', '', sanitized_term,flags=re.UNICODE)
```

that's all